# TFS keep test results for release environment

Tags: tfs, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am testing automated releases on TFS 2017.

My release definition currently has one environment. A release was triggered once every day, so by the time I can see a number of releases. For every release I can see the outcome for the environment (Succeeded, Partially Succeeded or Failed).
But the test results are kept only for the latest release as it seems. If I open an older release and go to "Tests", it says "No test results are available. To run automated tests, add Test tasks to your release definition".
Only if I open the latest release, I can see all the tests with their individual results.

In the settings of TFS under Test, "Days to keep automated test runs, results, and attachments" is set to "Never delete".
If I edit my release definition and go to Retention, "Days to retain a release" is set to 60 and the minimum releases to keep is set to 3. "Retain build" is NOT checked.

Is "Retain build" the reason why I loose individual test results of older releases?
Or should I mark a release to "Retain indefinitely" to also keep the test results?
What is the best way if I want to keep individual test results for a release?

Comment: How did you run the tests in release? Based on your retention policy settings the test result will not be deleted. So, please check if the tests were really excuted in the releases.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, please check if the tests are executed in release.

Generally we can get the test result with the test run ID ([Get a test result](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/test/results#get-a-test-result)). So, just refer to the release logs to check if there are any test runs. You can also check that with REST API: [Get task log](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/rm/releases#get-task-log). If no test runs there, that means no tests were executed.

To keep the test results in releases, just make sure your retention policies (Test, build and release) do not delete the needed builds/release with the test results.

If you select `Automated test results` in your build retention policy, then the test runs, results and attachments will also be deleted when a build is deleted.

So, if the the build linked to a release has its own retention policy, which may be shorter than that of the release. If you want to retain the build for the same period as the release, set the **Retain build** checkbox for the appropriate environments. This overrides the retention policy for the build. See [Build and release retention policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/vsts/build-release/concepts/policies/retention) for details.

In your scenario, if you can see the test runs in logs, then just try to uncheck the option `Automated test results` in build retention policy and keep "**Retain build**" checked, then try that again.

Comment: I have checked "Retain build". It seems that now test results for recent releases are kept. The build retention policy, is it the retention for the primary artifact build? A release does not include a build, it only is linked to artifacts.